# Conditionals: How is the syntax for a multiline if statement in Elm?

Tags: elm

I am reading the Elm chapter of the book *Seven More Languages in Seven Weeks*.
On page 43 the author describes a multi line `if` in the following way:

```
x = 5

if | x < 0 -> "too small" \
   | x > 0 -> "too big" \
   | otherwise -> "just right"
```

However, the Elm-REPL complains about a `SYNTAX PROBLEM`:

```
> if | x < 0 -> "too small" \
|    | x > 0 -> "too big" \
|    | otherwise -> "just right"
-- SYNTAX PROBLEM -------------------------------------------- repl-temp-000.elm

I ran into something unexpected when parsing your code!

3|   if | x < 0 -> "too small" 
        ^
I am looking for one of the following things:

    an expression
    whitespace
```

- **How is the syntax for a multiline if statement?**

---

In the documentation (http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax) I found the usage of 
nested `if`-`else` statements. Is it possible to create multiline statements like
described in the book?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The multi-way `if` syntax was removed in Elm 0.16. Here is the [blog post discussing the change](http://elm-lang.org/blog/compilers-as-assistants#removing-syntax).

You can use `else if` and `else` to achieve the functionality you are after.

```elm
if x < 0 then
    "too small"
else if x > 0 then
    "too big"
else
    "just right
```